# legend title do not work on MatLab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to put a title on my legend function in my matlab code, and it does not work. i use the MatLab official help on their site, but it does not change anything.

my code:

```
stem(100,300,'blue', 'Marker', '*', 'MarkerSize', 4,'LineStyle', '-');
hold on
stem(80,500,'green', 'Marker', '*', 'MarkerSize', 4,'LineStyle', '-');
hold on
stem(30,1400,'red', 'Marker', '*', 'MarkerSize', 4,'LineStyle', '-');
axis([0 150 0 2000]);
hold off
lgd=legend('100%','80%','30%','Location','northeastoutside');
**title(lgd,'My Legend Title','FontSize',12);**
xlabel('DoD(%)','fontname','times','fontsize',16);
ylabel('Number of cycles','fontname','times','fontsize',16);
```

from Matlab site i took this code

```
x = -pi:pi/20:pi;
y1 = sin(x);
plot(x,y1)

hold on
y2 = cos(x);
plot(x,y2)
hold off

lgd = legend('sin(x)','cos(x)');
**title(lgd,'My Legend Title')**
```

but still the plot don't change nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
set(get(lgd,'Title'),'String','My Legend Title')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for earlier versions of Matlab.

I suppose il_raffa is right - Setting `title` for `legend` is supported in Matlab 2016a and above (I think).

Download `legendTitle` from here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48331-add-a-title-to-a-legend

You may use the following code sample:

```
stem(100,300,'blue', 'Marker', '*', 'MarkerSize', 4,'LineStyle', '-');
hold on
stem(80,500,'green', 'Marker', '*', 'MarkerSize', 4,'LineStyle', '-');
hold on
stem(30,1400,'red', 'Marker', '*', 'MarkerSize', 4,'LineStyle', '-');
axis([0 150 0 2000]);
hold off
lgd=legend('100%','80%','30%','Location','northeastoutside');

xlabel('DoD(%)','fontname','times','fontsize',16);
ylabel('Number of cycles','fontname','times','fontsize',16);

if verLessThan('matlab', '9.0')
    %Before Matalb 2016a, use legendTitle (downloaded from MathWorks file exchange).
    set(lgd, 'Position', get(lgd, 'Position').*[1, 0.9, 1, 1]);
    legendTitle(lgd, 'My Legend Title','FontSize',12);
else
    %Matalb 2016a and above, use title (built in function).
    title(lgd,'My Legend Title','FontSize',12);
end
```

---

Matlab **2016a**:
[image]

---

Matlab **2014b**:
[image]

---

Matlab **2012b**:
[image]